# Multi-tenant Project

Tags: php, multi-tenant

I want to make my eCommerce website multi-tenancy every registered user has its own database and subdomain, but I want to make this in pure PHP I don't use laravel as a framework.

Is there any package for that?

I have made a multi-database, database for every user when he registered I did it, but I can't make a subdomain for every user

Comment: I would have a config file that maps the supplied domain to a database. The config file could also be a global database but you'd probably want to cache that.

Comment: Use a wildcard DNS entry for the third level domain and then point that to an IP-based site instead of name-based. Then in your landing page, pull the domain that was hit out of `$_SERVER` and use that to determine which database you use. This will allow you to add sites on the fly -- without the need to add a DNS record for each site, without the need to add a vhost for each site, and without the need to restart the web server each time a site is added.

Comment: thank you, can I do that for a subdomain? my main domain is a subdomain (subdomain. mydomain.com) can I do it for every user (user1.mysubdomain.mydomain.com), etc. or not?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a wildcard DNS record . Which will create a subdomain for every user . Then on every request check $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and change database based on it.
Some GitHub projects can be checked which done on same way.

https://github.com/masum0009/clcknshop

https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant